# Convert pdf to docx format in python

Tags: pdf, docx, python-docx, pdfminer

Please how do I convert pdf to docx. I tried converting to html using pdfminer to extract the text but still doesn't look good enough.

Comment: Could you explain more about the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

***pdf2docx***

1. Install the pdf2docx package Click [here](https://github.com/dothinking/pdf2docx)

***Installation***

- Clone or download pdf2docx

  ```
   pip install pdf2docx
       or
   # download the package and install your environment
   python setup.py install
  ```
- Option 1

  ```
  from pdf2docx import Converter

  pdf_file  = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/Document1.pdf'# source file 
  docx_file = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/sample.docx'  # destination file

  # convert pdf to docx
  cv = Converter(pdf_file)
  cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
  cv.close()

  #Output

  Parsing Page 53: 53/53...
  Creating Page 53: 53/53...
  --------------------------------------------------
  Terminated in 6.258919400000195s.
  ```
- Option 2

  ```
  from pdf2docx import parse

  pdf_file  = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/Document2.pdf' # source file
  docx_file = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/sample_2.docx' # destination file

  # convert pdf to docx
  parse(pdf_file, docx_file, start=0, end=None)

  # output
  Parsing Page 53: 53/53...
  Creating Page 53: 53/53...
  --------------------------------------------------
  Terminated in 5.883666100000482s.
  ```

Comment: Is this supported on Linux?